# fastest way to read the last line of a string?

Tags: c++, string, stdstring

I'd like to know the fastest way for reading the last line in a `std::string` object.
Technically, the string after the last occurrence of `\n` in the fastest possible way?

Comment: How does `std::basic_string::find_last_of` followed by `std::basic_string::substr` perform?

Comment: Fast to write, fast to debug, fast to execute, or some other manner of fast?

Comment: @user4581301 fast to execute of course. But if there's already a C++ function for that, I won't mind because it'd be more secure && less-code.

Comment: Agreed. That's the best place to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably use [std::string::rfind](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind) and  [std::string::substr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) combined with guaranteed [std::string::npos](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos) wrap around to be succinct:

```
inline std::string last_line_of(std::string const& s)
{
    return s.substr(s.rfind('\n') + 1);
}
```

If `s.rfind('\n')` doesn't find anything it returns [std::string::npos](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos). The `C++` standard says `std::string::npos + 1 == 0`. And returning `s.substr(0)` is always safe.

If `s.rfind('\n')` does find something then you want the substring starting from the next character. Again returning `s.substr(s.size())` is safe according to the standard.

**NOTE:** In `C++17` this method will benefit from *guaranteed return value optimization* so it should be super efficient.

Comment: this answer is better than mine, didn't know about the npos bit

Comment: @kmdreko Some will argue that yours is clearer (which it is - I upvoted it), so its six of one and half a dozen of the other.

Comment: I did some testing and it turns out that `rfind` if faster than `find_last_of` when it comes to single characters.

Comment: interesting, I'd think they'd have the same implementation for the single char case...

Answer (score 6):

This can be done using just `string::find_last_of` and `string::substr` like so

```
std::string get_last_line(const std::string &str)
{
  auto position = str.find_last_of('\n');
  if (position == std::string::npos)
    return str;
  else
    return str.substr(position + 1);
}
```

see: [example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dppk4ulbmM69pqKg)

Answer (score 0):

I thought of a way that reads the string inversely (backwards) while storing what it reads

```
std::string get_last_line(const std::string &str)
{
    size_t l = str.length();
    std::string last_line_reversed, last_line;
    for (--l; l > 0; --l)
    {
        char c = str.at(l);
        if (c == '\n')
            break;
        last_line_reversed += c;
    }
    l = last_line_reversed.length();
    size_t i = 0, y = l;
    for (; i < l; ++i)
        last_line += last_line_reversed[--y];
    return last_line;
}
```

until it counters a `'\n'` character then reverse the stored string back and return it. If the target string is big and has a lot of new lines, this function would be very efficient.

Comment: `at` is great. It's an excellent debugging tool, but when you're after speed, the extra validity tests `at` performs slow you down.

Comment: Recommend an annotation to warn users that this function will misbehave if given an empty string. `for (--l; l > 0; --l)` when `l` is zero will end badly.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you, I just wrote it in hurry without any if-checking to only pass the idea to SO.